# Why isn't the read only [] operator used?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, readonly, read-write

I'm currently writing an `Polynomial`-class in C++, which should represent an polynomial of the following form:

```
p(x) = a_0 + a_1*x^1 + a_2*x^2 + ... + a_i*x^i
```

where `a_0, ..., a_i` are all `int`'s.

The class internally uses an member variable `a_` of type`std::vector<int>` to store the constant factors `a_0, ..., a_i`. To access the constant factors the `operator[]` is overloaded in the following way:

**Read and write:**

```
int &operator[](int i)
{
  return a_.at(i);
}
```

This will fail when trying to change one of the factors `a_i` with:

```
i > degree of polynomial = a_.size() - 1
```

**Read-only:**

```
int operator[](int i) const
{
  if (i > this->degree()) {
    return 0;
  }

  return a_.at(i);
}
```

The slightly different implementation allows rather comfortable looping over the factors of two different sized polynomials (without worrying about *the degree* of the polynomial).

Sadly I seem to miss something here, since the `operator+`-overloading (which makes use of this comfortable *read-only*-`operator[]`) fails.

**`operator+`-overloading**:

```
Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial &other) {
  Polynomial res(this->degree() + other.degree());

  for (int i = 0; i <= res.degree(); ++i) {
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; ++k) {
      res[i] += (*this)[k] * other[i-k];
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

Don't mind the math involved. The important point is, that the `i` is always in the range of

```
0 <= i < res.a_.size()
```

thus writing to `res[i]` is valid. However `(*this)[k]` and `other[i-k]` try to read from indices which don't necessarily lay in the range `[0, (*this).a_.size() - 1]`.

This should be fine with our *read-only*-implementation of the `operator[]` right? I still get an error trying to access `a_` at invalid indices. What could cause the compiler to use the **read-write**-implementation in the line:

```
res[i] += (*this)[k] * other[i-k];
```

*Especially the part on the right side of the equality.*

I'm certain the error is caused by the "wrong" use of the **read-and-write**-`operator[]`. Because with an additional check fixes the invalid access:

```
if (k <= this->degree() && i-k <= other.degree()) {
  res[i] += (*this)[k] * other[i-k];
}
```

What am I missing with the use of the `operator[]`-overloading? Why isn't the **read-only**-`operator[]` used here?

Comment: The binary `operator*` should normally be `const`.

Comment: It is counter-intuitive and confusing to have `[ ]` do different things.  The programmer is expecting the same behavior.

Comment: Prefer a non-member `Polynomial operator*(Polynomial const& lhs, Polynomial const& rhs)`, since you don't need any privileged access to `this`. And yes, `at` would be better than a magical `[]` that sometimes does what you want ...

Comment: This question is a good example of a complete lack of trying to narrow the code down to the relevant part.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Do you think I should fail on invalid **read-only** access as well?

Comment: @Herickson  Imagine if your class was used in a more complex program, where the behavior of returning 0 was not expected by the programmer, and causes a hard-to-find bug.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry, indeed this question can be broke down quite a bit, but I like to add some context.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So the *fail on invalid access*-approach is preferred?

Comment: @Herickson - Why should you access invalid indices in the first place?  The "read-only" return of 0 on an invalid access could be masking a potential **real** bug.

Comment: But did you ever ask yourself if the readers want to read through all the context? I mean, the question is well written and fun to read, but having made it to the end, I could now imagine a ten-line version of it that makes the same point, and I wish this had been that question. Sorry for picking on you, but it's rare to see a question that has this problem but is generally good. (Usually this problem appears in completely hopeless questions.)

Comment: I think deciding on a single approach which is consistent across both `[]` overloads is preferred. It's your choice whether you care more about performance (and should stick with `vector::operator []`'s UB) or ease-of-use (and should use `vector::at` in both places), or something else.

Comment: @Herickson Also, if you later plan on overloading `operator *=`, it is better to implement that operator first, and then call `operator*` in terms of `operator *=`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I definitely see your point. I'll take some time and rewrite it so future readers can profit from the knowledge in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(*this)[k]` is using the non-const `this` as the function containing it is not `const`.

Hence the non-const overload of `[]` is preferred by the compiler.

You could get round this using an ugly `const_cast`, but really you ought to keep the behaviour of the two versions of the `[]` operator as similar as possible. Besides, the `std::vector` overload of `[]` doesn't insist on the index being bounds checked, as opposed to `at` which must be. Your code is a deviation from this and therefore could confuse readers of your code.

Comment: Thank you really much. Actually the `operator*` overload is `const` thus no `const_cast` necessary. I'll accept the answer as soon as possible.